# search on a table and linked tables with fulltext

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a simple database like this:

```
table "contents":
--------------------------
CID | contentName
  1 | Watermelon

table "tags":
--------------------------
TID | tagName | tagKeywords
 77 | Fruit   | Fruit, fruits
 99 | Nature  | nature, green, mother earth

table "associations":
--------------------------
CID | TID
  1 | 77
  1 | 99
```

how should I write a select that searches in the table "contents" with every row inheriting any associated tag's keywords?

for instance if i search "fruit" and "green" the fulltext search should result more relevant because matches two tags

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is more what you're looking for:

```
SELECT c.contentName, GROUP_CONCAT(tagkeywords separator ',')
FROM contents c
INNER JOIN associations a ON a.CID = c.CID
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.TID = a.TID
GROUP BY c.contentName;
```

I just tested it, and got the following:

```
contentName    GROUP_CONCAT(tagkeywords separator ',')
-----------    ---------------------------------------
Watermelon     Fruit, fruits,nature,green,mother earth
```

Comment: yes ok... but this 1 row = 1 tag, what i want is, 1 row all tags

Comment: I don't see why not.  Give it a shot and test it out.

Comment: doesn't work! works only in boolean mode (slow) according to mysql's site so a different solution is needed... do you have any idea?

Comment: The MATCH() column list must match exactly the column list in some FULLTEXT index definition for the table, unless this MATCH() is IN BOOLEAN MODE. Boolean-mode searches can be done on nonindexed columns, although they are likely to be slow.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html